# MongoDB: queries doesn't always return all documents

Tags: mongodb

Queries doesn't always return all matching documents, that's really weird, isn't it ?  Any idea about this behaviour ?

Thanks in advance

```
mongoose.connect(config.mongoUrl); 

mongoose.connection.on('error',function (err) {
    console.log("Error: " + err); 
});

User.find({"Role" : "User"}, function (err, users) {
    if (err) { throw err; }

    for (user in users){
        user =  users[user];               
        console.log(user.Role +  "  " + user.Email1);                                                                       
    }

}).then(function(doc) {
    console.log("finish User Update");
    process.exit();
});
```

Comment: I don't think you should use a promise `.then` after your query. You are already handling the callback with the function defined after the query `{"Role": "Users"}`. Try to call `process.exit()` after the for cycle where you log user roles and emails

Comment: Yes you are right! the problem was process.exit()